# Returning value from for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, return

How can I get the value *points* returned from for loop for value *addressPoints*? console log of responce.loc and points provide the right result.

```
var index;
var points =[];
for (index=0;index<ip_export.length;index++) { 

    console.log(ip_export[index]);

$.get("http://ipinfo.io/"+ip_export[index], function(response) {
    console.log(response.loc);
    points.push(response.loc);
    //console.log(points);
}, "jsonp");

return points;  
//return points;    
console.log(points);
}

var addressPoints = JSON.stringify(points);
```

Comment: `$.get` is asynchronous. :\

Comment: OK, thanks, how can I solve it?